# Java Method isn't implementing what it is supposed to

Tags: java, object, oop, methods

Hey everyone very new to coding!
So I was trying to make a calculator program using object oriented programming in Java however when I try to call my method for addition it doesn't do the job entirely so what am I doing wrong here ?
Thanks in advance :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class CalculatorOOP {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static double currentValue;

    public double valueInput;
    
    public CalculatorOOP(double valueTyped){

        valueTyped = currentValue;
    }
    
    public double addToValue(){

        System.out.println("Type the value you want to add:");
        double valueToAdd = input.nextDouble();

         double valueAfterAddition = CalculatorOOP.currentValue + valueToAdd;

        return valueAfterAddition;

    }
    
    public double substractToValue(){

        System.out.println("Type the value you want to substract:");

        double valueToSubstract = input.nextDouble();

        double valueAfterSubstraction = 
CalculatorOOP.currentValue - valueToSubstract;

        return valueAfterSubstraction;
    }
    
    public double multiplyValue(){

        System.out.println("Type the factor value:");

        double factor = input.nextDouble();

        double valueAfterMultiplication = CalculatorOOP.currentValue * factor;

        return valueAfterMultiplication;
    }
        
    public double divideValue(){

        System.out.println("Type the divisor value:");

        double divisor = input.nextDouble();

        double valueAfterDivision = CalculatorOOP.currentValue / divisor;

        return valueAfterDivision;
    }
    }




import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a value:");

        double valueInput = input.nextDouble();

        CalculatorOOP obj = new CalculatorOOP(valueInput);

        System.out.println("Enter the calculation option (1, 2, 3, or 4):");

        int optionEntered = input.nextInt();

        switch (optionEntered){

            case 1 : obj.addToValue();

        }


        }}
```

Here this is what I get when running the code however it is not performing the addition it is just asking for values

```
Type a value:
2
Enter the calculation option (1, 2, 3, or 4):
1
Type the value you want to add:
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: How do you know it's not performing the addition, if you're never displaying the result of any operation, or in fact doing anything with said result? Also, in your constructor, this bit should be reversed: `valueTyped = currentValue;`

Answer (score 1):

Your `addToValue` method seems to perform the addition correctly and return the calculated sum. Where you call the method, you are not picking up the return value — so it just disappears, is discarded. I believe you want to assign it back into `CalculatorOOP.currentValue` and/or print it. Either from inside the method or from where you called it.